# Hide and show svg element with transition

Tags: d3.js

How can I hide and show an svg element using transition?
I try this code:

```
<div id="bubble"></div>
<div id="buttonHide"><button>Hide</button></div>
<div id="buttonShow"><button>Show</button></div>

d3.select("#bubble")
    .append("svg")
    .append("g")
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "bubble")
    .attr("transform", "translate(100, 100)")
    .attr("r", 50)
    .attr("fill", "black");

d3.select("#buttonHide").on("click", function() {
    d3.select(".bubble").transition().attr('visibility', 'hidden').duration(1000);
});

d3.select("#buttonShow").on("click", function() {
    d3.select(".bubble").transition().attr('visibility', 'visible').duration(1000);
});
```

```js
d3.select("#bubble")
 .append("svg")
 .append("g")
 .append("circle")
 .attr("class", "bubble")
 .attr("transform", "translate(100, 100)")
 .attr("r", 50)
 .attr("fill", "black");

d3.select("#buttonHide").on("click", function() {
 d3.select(".bubble").transition().duration(1000).attr('visibility', 'hidden');
});

d3.select("#buttonShow").on("click", function() {
 d3.select(".bubble").transition().duration(1000).attr('visibility', 'visible');
});
```

```html
<html lang='en'>
 <head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <script src='https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js' charset='utf-8'></script>
 </head>

 <body>
  
  <div id="bubble"></div>
  <div id="buttonHide"><button>Hide</button></div>
  <div id="buttonShow"><button>Show</button></div>
  
 </body>
</html>
```

But transition doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could play with the `opacity` style instead of switching the `visibility` attribute:

```js
d3.select("#bubble")
 .append("svg")
 .append("g")
 .append("circle")
 .attr("class", "bubble")
 .attr("transform", "translate(100, 100)")
 .attr("r", 50)
 .attr("fill", "black")
 .style("opacity", 1);

d3.select("#buttonHide").on("click", function() {
 d3.select(".bubble").transition().duration(1000).style("opacity", 0);
});

d3.select("#buttonShow").on("click", function() {
 d3.select(".bubble").transition().duration(1000).style("opacity", 1);
});
```

```html
<html lang='en'>
 <head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <script src='https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js' charset='utf-8'></script>
 </head>

 <body>

  <div id="bubble"></div>
  <div id="buttonHide"><button>Hide</button></div>
  <div id="buttonShow"><button>Show</button></div>
  
 </body>
</html>
```

This way, the transition will be applied on the opacity, which will transition from `0` to `1` (unhide) or from `1` to `0` (hide).

To set the opacity:

```
d3.select(".bubble").transition().duration(1000).style("opacity", 1);
```

The `transition` is in fact expecting a change which can be interpolated between two values. This is the case for the opacity (all the way between 0 and 1), whereas the visibility attribute is a simple switch (on/off).